# Given the week number, how to find the start date of that particular week?

Tags: formula-field, date

Given the week number, how to find the start date of that particular week using a Formula Field?

Answer (score 1):

**If January 1st is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, that is [Week 01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week).**

Based on that, given the week number for the current year, the first date (Monday) of that week is:

```
CASE(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1)),
2, (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1) - 0) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
3, (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1) - 1) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
4, (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1) - 2) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
5, (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1) - 3) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
6, (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1) + 3) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
7, (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1) + 2) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
1, (DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1) + 1) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
null)
```

---

If calculating for another year (`Testing_Year__c`):

```
CASE(WEEKDAY(DATE(Testing_Year__c, 1, 1)),
2, (DATE(Testing_Year__c, 1, 1) - 0) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
3, (DATE(Testing_Year__c, 1, 1) - 1) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
4, (DATE(Testing_Year__c, 1, 1) - 2) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
5, (DATE(Testing_Year__c, 1, 1) - 3) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
6, (DATE(Testing_Year__c, 1, 1) + 3) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
7, (DATE(Testing_Year__c, 1, 1) + 2) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
1, (DATE(Testing_Year__c, 1, 1) + 1) + ((Week_Number__c - 1) * 7),
null)
```